# Identify line break from MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing a system that works that way:

- select a mysql table
- select a mysql row
- extract the data from that row (using WHERE and AND)
- display te data using php

However, in one of the rows, the parameters are stored using line breaks, and I need that my system identify this line break, and the 'send' as new value.

Code:

```
foreach($rows as $row){ 
$ips = $row['dedicatedip'];
$ips2 = $row['assignedips'];
$status = $row['domainstatus'];

echo '<b>', $ips . '&nbsp;&nbsp;-</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;'; echo "<input type='text' value="; echo consultaIP($ips);  echo ">"; echo '<b> Status:'; if ($status==Active) { echo ' <span class="label active">Ativo</span></b><br><br>';} else { echo ' <span class="label pending">Desativado</span></b><br/><br/>';}

if ($ips2 != '') { echo '<b>', $ips2 . '&nbsp;&nbsp;-</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;'; echo "<input type='text' value="; echo consultaIP($ips);  echo ">"; echo '<b> Status:'; if ($status==Active) { echo ' <span class="label active">Ativo</span></b><br><br>';} else { echo ' <span class="label pending">Desativado</span></b><br/><br/>';} }
}
```

PS: function consultaIP is a function that lookups the IP reverse DNS.

The dedicatedip row have just one value stored, so it's ok. But the assigned IP's, have a buch, stored like this:

```
177.101.0.100
177.101.0.101
177.101.0.102
```

The problem is that the system need to create the input for each IP, and this is not happening (it's showing like this: 177.101.0.100 177.101.0.101 177.101.0.102).

Those values will not get back to the database, so this will not be problem. It'll be used in the POST form.

Edit:

---

I've added this line:

```
chars = explode("\n", $ips2);
```

And the array looks like that:

Array ( [0] => 177.101.229.92 [1] => 177.101.229.80 )

But, how can I use this array output in my foreach, and correctly populate the input?

---

Solved:

```
$chars = explode("\n", $ips2);

foreach($chars as $iplista){
if ($ips2 != '') { echo '<b>', $iplista . '&nbsp;&nbsp;-</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;'; echo "<input     type='text' value="; echo consultaIP($ips);  echo ">"; echo '<b> Status:'; if ($status==Active) { echo ' <span class="label active">Ativo</span></b><br><br>';} else { echo ' <span class="label pending">Desativado</span></b><br/><br/>';} }
}
```

Comment: Maybe using the [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function?

Comment: Use [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Well done while I've been away. ;-) And thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do understand correct, you want an array of IP addresses to process on every single IP?

You can use the [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string, e.g. on newline char `"\n"`. If you don't know the newline sequence (\r, \n, or \r\n) or the input could vary, you could use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead to split by a regular expression, e.g. `\s` for all whitespaces or `(\r|\n|\r\n)` for system independent line break.

Comment: Hi, i updated the question.. can you please help me now? Thanks